# Recording time spend in a tab using Flurry Analytics

Tags: ios, flurry

I currently have multiple tabs within my application. What I would like to do is record the amount of time the user spends in the selected tab using Flurry Analytics. 
Usually I would start recording when `viewDidAppear` is call and stop recording when the `viewDidDisappear` method is called.

viewDidAppear

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"Tab_News" withParameters:nil timed:YES];
```

viewDidDisappear

```
[Flurry endTimedEvent:@"Tab_News" withParameters:nil];
```

My problem is that when a video gets played within the tab the `viewDidDisappear` and `viewDidAppear` methods get called even thought the user doesnt physically leave the tab.

Please help me with suggestions as to how I can circumvent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BOOL` called `videoPlaying` to track if a video is being played. When you play the video set it to `YES`. In `viewDidDisappear` only `endTimedEvent` `if (videoPlaying == NO)`

The same applies to `viewDidAppear`. If `videoPlaying == YES` don't `logEvent` and then set `videoPlaying = NO`.

Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _videoPlaying = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    if (_videoPlaying == YES) {
        _videoPlaying = NO;
    } else {
        [Flurry logEvent:@"Tab_News" withParameters:nil timed:YES];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear
{
   if (_videoPlaying == NO) {
      [Flurry endTimedEvent:@"Tab_News" withParameters:nil];
   }
}

- (void)playVideo
{
    _videoPlaying = YES;
    // Play video
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 6, you can do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [Flurry logEvent:@"Tab_News" withParameters:nil timed:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [Flurry endTimedEvent:@"Tab_News" withParameters:nil];
}
```

This is valid if you present this ViewController as soon as it's loaded.